# my xpath is correct, but selenium doesn't see the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

My code:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//svg[@class='SvgIcon_root__keb_Y'][@aria-label='Вернуться к старому дизайну']").click()`

My error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//svg[@class='SvgIcon_root__keb_Y'][@aria-label='Вернуться к старому дизайну']"}`

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS1QH.png)

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't Selenium find him? Because of focusable="false" and aria-hidden="true"?
If because of this, how do I identify this element and click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the the `SVG` element,the `xpath` should be different. It should be like.

```
//*[local-name()='svg' and @aria-label='Вернуться к старому дизайну']
```

Or

```
//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='SvgIcon_root__keb_Y']
```

Or

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Вернуться к старому дизайну']
```

Ideally your code should be like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @aria-label='Вернуться к старому дизайну']").click()
```

You can find following reference, how to interact with `svg` element
[xpathforsvgelement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements)